# programming secant method with a table of outputs for each iterations

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

Im currently learning about numerical methods in my numerical analysis course
and wanted to program [Secant Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) for finding roots of an equation in python

I checked different sources for that ([for example](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/%7Epwalls/math-python/roots-optimization/secant/)) and found really helpful codes on this method.
i even have one on my own with output on a given function.

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
  f = pow(x, 3) - pow(x,2)-1
  return f

def secant(x1, x2, E):
  n = 0
  xm = 0
  x0 = 0
  c = 0
  if (f(x1) * f(x2) < 0):
     while True:
        x0 = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) / (f(x2) - f(x1)))
        c = f(x1) * f(x0)
        x1 = x2
        x2 = x0
        n += 1
        if (c == 0):
            break
        xm = ((x1 * f(x2) - x2 * f(x1)) / (f(x2) - f(x1)))
        if (np.abs((xm - x0)/x0) < E):
            break

    print("Root of the given equation =", np.round(x0, 6))
    print("No. of iterations = ", n)

else:
    print("Can not find a root in the given inteval")


x1 = 1
x2 = 2
E = 0.0001
secant(x1, x2, E)
```

then I wanted to create such table for each iteration
(this is for bisection method not secant)
[image]
but i failed to do so.

i would really appreciate if someone can help me to do that.
even a hint would be appriciated.

Comment: Could you reduce the method code to the actual lines of the secant method? There is no sign condition, there should only be one midpoint computed per iteration, either x0 or xm, one of them should be removed. The test for the function value is of dubious utility, comparing to zero should be avoided.

Comment: Are you asking about a print statement of the form `print(f"{n:2d}  {x1:20.10f}  {x2:20.10f}")` etc., or is the output intended to be included in some other document markup like LaTeX?